# Express.js Server with iOS Swift Request Timing Out

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, swift, express

I am trying to make an HTTP POST request using an iOS Swift app to an Express.js server. In the post request, I send JSON data, creating the JSON object using a dict and SwiftyJSON. However, the request continues to time out. I think it has something to do with 'body-parser', which is what I am using to parse the HTTP body. Here is my swift code:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    var dict  = ["name": "FirstChannel", "verified": 0, "private": 1, "handle": "firstChannel", "subscribers": 0] as [String : Any]
    var jsonData = JSON(dict)

    do {
        let post:NSData = try jsonData.rawData() as NSData
        var postLength: NSString = String(post.length) as NSString
        var url = URL(string: "http://10.0.0.220:3000/channel/createChannel")!
        var request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.httpBody = post as Data
        request.setValue(postLength as String, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

        NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request as URLRequest, queue: OperationQueue.main, completionHandler: { (resposne, data, error) in
            if(error != nil) {
                print(error)
            }
            else {
                print(data)
            }
        })



    }
    catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

And here is the code I use in my express.js router:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var util = require('util');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;

router.use(bodyParser.json());
router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/my_db');

var channelSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  verified: String,
  private: String,
  channelID: String,
  handle: String,
  subscribers: String
});

var Channel = mongoose.model("Channel", channelSchema);
router.post('/createChannel', bodyParser, function(req, res, next) {
    req.body = true;
    if(!req.body) return res.sendStatus(400);
    var objID = new ObjectID();

    var newChannel = new Channel({
       name: req.body["name"],
       verified: req.body["verified"],
       private: req.body["private"],
       channelID: objID,
       handle: req.body["handle"],
       subscribers: (req.body["subscribers"])
  });

newChannel.save(function(err, point){
  if(err) console.log(err);
  else res.end();
});

});
```

If anybody could help me out and help this POST request succeed, I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like you're sending back an `HTTP 200` on success of your route - you only handle an error. Add a `res.end();` at the end of your route (probably in the callback from the DB call) and try again.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response. I added the res.end(); at the end of the DB save call, but the request is still timing out. Any other ideas?

Comment: You were correct about my response being empty. I also needed to send the point object I declared in my database save callback.